# Function Output Format when calling from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, formatting

This is the function I am using in python:

```
def seqmatchsequence(raw_input):
records = list(SeqIO.parse(raw_input, "fasta"))
d = dict()
for record in records:
    if record.seq in d:
        d[record.seq].append(record)
    else:
        d[record.seq] = [record]
for seq, record_set in d.items():
    if (len(record_set)) != 1:
        print(': (' + str(len(record_set)) + ')')
    for record in record_set:
        if (len(record_set)) != 1:
            print(record.id)
```

My output looks like this:

```
: (2)
chr1:930227-930591
chr1:948374-948738
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
: (2)
chr1:930227-930591, chr1:948374-948738
```

I tried everything I could think of, but I am missing something, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is not returning anything--you are simply having it print strings to stdout.

If you want to return the values as you prefer, string these together into a single string. You now have the option to print the single string (as you do now):

```
    for seq, record_set in d.items():
        str_out = None
        if (len(record_set)) != 1:
            str_out = ': (' + str(len(record_set)) + ')')
        for record in record_set:
            if (len(record_set)) != 1:
                str_out += ', ' + record.id
        print(str_out)
```

Or you can return the same string:

```
    return(str_out)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works out well, I appreciate the help!